# What is the best practice for handling transaction commit error?

Tags: apache-pulsar

In distributed transactions, when my local database transaction succeeds but consuming messages or committing message transactions fails, should I rollback the message transaction and reset the message consumption status, while also rolling back the database transaction? Can I choose not to rollback the database transaction and only re-confirm message consumption or recommit the message transaction?

After reviewing the official documentation's examples, it is not explicitly stated regarding these details.